# remove outline for <li> element after making it not editable

Tags: jquery, html

After I click ENTER on an editable <li> element, I want to simple exit editing mode (no blinking cursor) and make <li> element not editable. I removed default orange outline, and it's not there when I'm typing. But once I hit ENTER it appears. Why it's there and how can I remove it? [Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjB3k/) and actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
[contenteditable="true"]:active,
[contenteditable="true"]:focus{
    border: 1px solid rgb(179,179,179);
    outline:0px solid transparent;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(
function() {
$('#click_me').click(function() {
    var item = "<li class='option-item new' contenteditable='true'>simple element2<li>"
    var container = $("#ctx-options");
    container.append(item);
    var $last = $(".option-item", container).last();
    //neither of these works
    $last.focus();
});

$("#ctx-options").on('keydown', '.option-item.new', function(e) {  
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('contentEditable', false);
    }
})

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="click_me">click me</span>
    <ul id="ctx-options"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the attribute to false, so the CSS selector `[contenteditable="true"]` no longer matches the element, and the outline becomes visible. Just do :

```
.option-item {outline: none;}
```

to solve it !

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjB3k/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following CSS to get rid of the orange outline:

```
li {
    outline-color: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/rjB3k/3/